# How do I find a package with a specific component in?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm building a few packages from source at the moment and they don't always list their dependencies so I'm playing a game of hunt the package.

For example:

```
No package 'xcb-composite' found
```

I can just google it and I'll find the correct package but is there a smarter way of doing it through apt or something else cli based?

Comment: It would help to know what packages you are trying to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ apt search xcb-composite
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libxcb-composite0/bionic-updates 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 amd64
  X C Binding, composite extension

libxcb-composite0-dev/bionic-updates 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 amd64
  X C Binding, composite extension, development files
```

Sometimes it also helps to search the internet for the error message.

[No package 'xcb-composite' found](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1797397):

> It built OK here earlier. Make sure that this is installed:
>   libxcb-composite0-dev.

To show a package's dependencies:

```
apt-cache showpkg <package-name>
```

Replace `<package-name>` with the name of the package.

The following command does the same thing as the previous command and in addition it has improved filtering that makes the results easier to read by showing only the package's dependencies:

```
apt-cache showpkg <package-name> | sed -n '/Dependencies:/,/^$/p'
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. OP is trying to build packages with multiple unknown dependencies, of which this is just one.

Comment: It does, I didn't realise that apt search can do partial matching. Following this and some trial and error runs I'm now compiling the package (polybar fwiw).

Comment: apt search can indeed do partial matching, but this statement would be deceptive if I didn't add that the regular expression pattern matching that apt search uses sometimes give users the naive impression that there is no matching package when actually there are matching packages in the software repositories. Unlike the Synaptic (*synaptic*) application which is 100% accurate and easier to read than `apt search`.